# Сделать бекап сайта на битрикс

Tags: битрикс, резервное-копирование

суть проблемы такова - есть сайт, сделанный на битриксе, его нужно перенести на другой сервер (то есть создать его копию) для того чтобы безболезненно тестировать разные новые штуки. Если я просто вытаскиваю все файлы через filezilla то после мне не удается развернуть сайт на локальном хосте так как видимо все пути внутри скриптов сбиваются. А если я использую опцию "резервное копирование"  в админ панели битрикса то потом скачиваются файлы, которые можно открыть только также через битрикс. И вот вопрос - как в таком случае правильно сделать бекап - копию сайта со всеми его данными из инфоблоков, чтобы я мог спокойно развернуть эту копию на локальном хосте?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Скачиваете бэкап, скачиваете оттуда же файл restore.php - http://joxi.ru/L21jk1oc0GxkQA

Заливаете все на локальный хостинг, открываете restore.php в браузере. Выбираете "Архив загружен в корневую папку сервера", а дальше по инструкции "далее - далее - далее".

Answer (score -12):

Не нужно ничего никуда заливать. Делаешь бекап средствами битрикса, на удаленный хостинг кидаешь только [restore.php](http://www.1c-bitrix.ru/download/scripts/restore.php). Переходишь в браузере на скрипт, выбираешь загрузку с url и вставляешь ссылку на твой бекап (ее получаешь в админке старого сайта). 120 файлов бекапов выкачивать и заливать через файлзиллу.

После этого битрикс ставится как родной

Comment: Почему меня минусуют?(

Comment: За а) деструктивные команды, которые удаляют данные, вы всё [пони рисуете, да?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10560/) б) за мат.